# Why is my unit test not detected?

Tags: 8, testing

I have a custom Drupal 8 module for which I'm trying to create unit tests by following the instructions at https://www.drupal.org/phpunit.

The path of my module is: `/modules/custom/dev_module`
The path of my tests is: `/modules/custom/dev_module/tests/src/Unit`

More specifically, in the `Unit` folder I have a `DummyTest.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\dev_module\Tests;

use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;

/**
 * My dummy test.
 *
 * @group dummy_test
 */
class DummyTest extends UnitTestCase {

  public function testDummy() {
    $this->assertEquals(5, 5);
  }

}
```

When executing the following commands from the terminal (I'm on Mac OS):

```
 > cd core
 > ../vendor/bin/phpunit --list-groups
```

My group `dummy_test` doesn't show up in the listed groups. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unit tests must have the following namespace: `Drupal\Tests\dev_module\Unit`.

For complicated reasons, they also don't show up in the right group but they are all in the PHPUnit group.

To run your unit tests with phpunit, just pass the module folder, that also makes it 10x faster for finding the tests:

`./vendor/bin/phpunit -c core modules/dev_module`

Comment: Thank you, Berdir. Your suggestion worked. I had noticed the `namespace Drupal\Tests\MODULE\Unit;` in the examples module but I had changed it since it didn't seem to work.